# Remove assigned territory in account

Tags: territory-management

How can we remove the assigned territory in the account after it's been auto-assigned via assignment rules?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the Accounts detail page beside the territory field there should be an option for changing the territory values. There you can select or deselect the values.

Comment: Hi Night, I've been assigned as Admin in the org and I cannot see the option beside the territory field, the truth is, assigned territories is a section on Account page rather than a field.